# Retorno de promise

Tags: javascript, async, meteor, promises

Considerando o exemplo abaixo:

```
function retornaValor (){
  return promiseQueveioDeAlgumaLib.then(
    function(oQueQueroRetornar){
      return {
        sucesso: true,
        data : oQueQueroRetornar
      }
    },
    function(opsAlgoErrado){
      return {
        sucesso : false,
        data : opsAlgoErrado
      }
    }
  )
}

console.log(retornaValor())
```

O que devo fazer para que eu tenha de fato `oQueQueroRetornar` ou `opsAlgoErrado` e não uma Promise pending?

Só pra constar: quando escrevo um código dessa forma dentro de `Meteor.methods` ele funciona exatamente como eu gostaria, ou seja, retorna um valor que devolvo pro cliente, mas fora de `methods` ou no cliente (browser, usando ou não qualquer framework) eu que eu tenho é uma Promise pending.

Comment: Você simplesmente não pode retornar de uma operação assíncrona. Quer dizer, as funções assíncronas até retornam, mas pra ninguém.

Comment: Acho que estás a tentar evitar um fluxo assíncrono e procuras uma maneira de fazer síncrono é isso? Nesse caso acho que tens mesmo de aceitar que algumas coisas são assincronas... se não fôr isso explica melhor a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Sim, eu preciso disso síncrono, o problema é que 101% das bibliotecas do Npm são assíncronas, o que me faz refém do Meteor/nodejs + fibers/future, que me permitem controlar isso.

Comment: Tu pode passar uma função de `callback` como parâmetro do `retornaValor`, e ao invés de retornar fazer um `callback({sucesso: true, data: oQueQueroRetornar});`, do outro lado você faria assim: `retornaValor(function(response) { console.log(response); });`

Comment: Sim eu posso, mas não resolveria, já que minha necessidade é que retornaValor() retorne de fato um valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você retornar o valor da promise você precisa tornar a sua operação síncrona, para que o log espere que a promise seja resolvida e então imprima o valor retornado. Isso pode ser feito utilizando a função await:

```
// Testando com uma promise qualquer.
let promiseQueveioDeAlgumaLib =         
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1').then(res => res.json());

function retornaValor() {
  return promiseQueveioDeAlgumaLib.then(
    function(oQueQueroRetornar) {
      return {
        sucesso: true,
        data : oQueQueroRetornar
      }
    },
    function(opsAlgoErrado) {
      return {
       sucesso : false,
       data : opsAlgoErrado
      }
    }
  );
}

console.log(await retornaValor());
```

O await força um comportamento síncrono na operação, ele vai garantir que a promise tenha resolvido antes de retornar o seu valor.

Para saber mais sobre promises e esse comportamento assíncrono, assim como boas práticas, recomendo a leitura [desse post](https://medium.com/@giu.drawer/operacoes-assincronas-javascript-promises-ae7553ad62b8).